# change project timeline to show hours based on working days, weeks or months

Tags: vba, excel, date

The given file shows the proper hours spread for projects, however, its timeline in range I5:JI5 doesnt show the correct working Months. The workdays come ok, the weeks i am assuming 5 workdays in a week, and the month i want to calculate accurately the no of working days in a month. for now, i am assuming 22 working days in a month. however the resultant workdays function does not yield me the right dates in the timeline.

e.g.

1. if you select DAY from dropdown and see the Actual End Dates, the days are
   all working days (excluding Sat,Sun) which is fine.
2. if you select WEEK from dropdown and see the Actual End Dates, the week dates are not the same. Also the hours are not falling correctly under the dates in the timeline.
3. if you select MONTH from dropdown and see the Actual End Dates, the month dates also are not the same. Also the hours are not falling correctly under their respective dates in the timeline.

what i mean is, ideally for all 3 options, the Actual End Dates should be the same and the hours should start from the Start Date on the timeline.

Here are the screenshots for the 3 options:
[image: When DAY is selected]

[image: When WEEK is selected]

[image: When MONTH is selected]

Here's the updated file (Shareable link):

[PSchedule Template.xlsx](https://1drv.ms/x/s!Am1wNPJDit1whx5eRTy_c1qb_tmE)

Comment: No-one's going to create an account to look at your file - you need to create a shareable upload.

Comment: What do you mean by when selecting Week, the End date is not the same? The same to what end of week (Friday)? What should be the value?

Comment: @TimWilliams, it is a public shareable link from my onedrive account. anyone with this link can edit or download this file. let me know if you want me to email it to you. Thanks.

Comment: If you see the Actual End Date, it is a little further than the Est. End Date. I put it there so that i could know what is the real end date, if the project hours are spread across the timeline as well as adjusted daily to 8 hours (changeable). Now, if i am right, even if i change the dropdown to show a Week or Month view, the Actual End Date should still reflect the same, as the hours would aggregate under that date....or am i wrong?

Comment: What do the day, week, month views do?

Comment: the Day view should show the timeline as consecutive working dates and the hours spread among them properly. The Week view should show the timeline as consecutive working weeks with the accumulated hours for each week, and similarly the Month view should show the timeline in Months and the accumulated hours in each month below them.

Comment: If everything is fine except the Actual End Date, ignore the value in drop down combo box and use the same process as Day views to calculate end date.

Comment: if you see the timeline workdates calculations, i am adding 1 for Day view, 5 (5 days in a week) for week view and assuming 22 days for month view. Day view will always be ok, as Workday (prev_column_date, 1) will give me the next workdate (excluding Sat, Sun), Workday (prev_column_date,5) will give me the next workdate, but i am not sure 22 acurately represents the days in that month to show me the correct next workdate next month.

Comment: ok, so lets keep the Day view which is fine. But when user selects Week view, then can we show "week 1" "Week 2" etc with the hours accumulated in each week? and if Month view, then show the Month name viz., Jan, Feb, Mar, etc and show the hours accumulated under each month? Hope you are getting my point?

Answer (score 1):

I have to say, this is one of those interesting questions.  Took me a while to come up with a simple solution.  I leave the how to populate the value on worksheet to OP :).

```
Dim aWork()
Dim iNoOfDay As Integer
Dim n As Integer
Dim dStart As Date
Dim dEnd As Date

Dim sCurPeriod As String
Dim sPeriod As String

Dim iCurPeriod As Integer
Dim dTotalPeriod As Double

sPeriod = "W" ' W = Weekly, M = Monthly
dStart = CDate("10 Jan 2016")
dEnd = CDate("12 Feb 2016")

iNoOfDay = DateDiff("d", dStart, dEnd)
' 0 - date, 1 - work hours, 2 - period starts from 1
ReDim aWork(iNoOfDay, 2)

iCurPeriod = 0

For n = 0 To iNoOfDay
    aWork(n, 0) = DateAdd("d", n, dStart)

    ' Set to 0 on weekends 1 = sunday, 7 = saturday may be different depending on your regional setting
    aWork(n, 1) = IIf(DatePart("w", aWork(n, 0)) <> 1 And DatePart("w", aWork(n, 0)) <> 7, 7.5, 0)

    If sPeriod = "W" Then
        If sCurPeriod <> DatePart("yyyy", aWork(n, 0)) & DatePart("ww", aWork(n, 0)) Then
            sCurPeriod = DatePart("yyyy", aWork(n, 0)) & DatePart("ww", aWork(n, 0))
            iCurPeriod = iCurPeriod + 1
        End If
    ElseIf sPeriod = "M" Then
        If sCurPeriod <> DatePart("yyyy", aWork(n, 0)) & DatePart("m", aWork(n, 0)) Then
            sCurPeriod = DatePart("yyyy", aWork(n, 0)) & DatePart("m", aWork(n, 0))
            iCurPeriod = iCurPeriod + 1
        End If
    End If

    aWork(n, 2) = iCurPeriod

Next

iCurPeriod = 0
For n = 0 To iNoOfDay
    If iCurPeriod <> aWork(n, 2) Then
        Debug.Print iCurPeriod, dTotalPeriod
        iCurPeriod = aWork(n, 2)
        dTotalPeriod = 0
    End If

    dTotalPeriod = dTotalPeriod + aWork(n, 1)
Next

Debug.Print iCurPeriod, dTotalPeriod
```

EDIT: The total per period calculation can be done in the first for next, I did it for the debugging.

Comment: this looks quite good, though i have not tested it. however i need a non-VBA solution - a formula to work in the date timeline. Can you help me with one?

Comment: I am more proficient in VBA than formula. I don't think it can be done easily with formula, but I could be wrong.